# Hyperbolic coordinates (Poincaré embeddings) as the output of a neural network

Tags: deep-learning, keras, manifold

I'm trying to build a Deep Learning predictor that takes as the input a set of word vectors (in Euclidian space) and outputs Poincaré embeddings. So far I am not having much luck, because model predicts arbitrary points in the n-dimensional real space, not the hyperbolic space. This causes the distance, and thus the loss function to be undefined. Therefore I need to restrict the output of the model somehow. I have tried several things.

First was defining the loss function that minimizes the Hyperbolic distance (on the Poincaré hyperdisc):

```
def distance_loss(u, v):
    max_norm = 1 - K.epsilon()

    sq_u_norm = K.clip(K.sum(K.pow(u, 2), axis=-1), 0, max_norm)
    sq_v_norm = K.clip(K.sum(K.pow(v, 2), axis=-1), 0, max_norm)

    sq_dist = K.sum(K.pow(u - v, 2), axis=-1)
    poincare_dist = tf.acosh(1 + (sq_dist / ((1 - sq_u_norm) * (1 - sq_v_norm))) * 2)
    neg_exp_dist = K.exp(-poincare_dist)
    return -K.log(neg_exp_dist)
```

Which I somewhat dumbly lifted from [here](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/poincare.py#L324) and [here](https://github.com/kousun12/tf_hyperbolic).

However that doesn't seem to work properly on it's own. Next up was to change the optimizer to something I lifted from [a notebook](https://github.com/kmkolasinski/deep-learning-notes/blob/master/seminars/2017-09-Poincare-Embeddings/notebooks/optimizers.py) on the topic, and [some slides (PDF)](https://github.com/kmkolasinski/deep-learning-notes/blob/master/seminars/2017-09-Poincare-Embeddings/slides.pdf). Note that I am using Keras 2.1.6 with Tensorflow, so I had to make some changes.

```
def get_normalization(p):
    p_norm = K.sum(K.square(p), -1, keepdims=True)
    mp = K.square(1 - p_norm)/4.0
    return mp, K.sqrt(p_norm)


def project(p, p_norm):
    p_norm_clip = K.maximum(p_norm, 1.0)
    p_norm_cond = K.cast(p_norm > 1.0, dtype='float') * K.epsilon()
    return p/p_norm_clip - p_norm_cond

class AdamPoincare(Adam):
    @interfaces.legacy_get_updates_support
    def get_updates(self,loss,params):
        grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
        self.updates = [K.update_add(self.iterations, 1)]

        lr = self.lr
        if self.initial_decay > 0:
            lr = lr * (1. / (1. + self.decay * K.cast(self.iterations,
                                                      K.dtype(self.decay))))

        t = K.cast(self.iterations, K.floatx()) + 1
        lr_t = lr * (K.sqrt(1. - K.pow(self.beta_2, t)) /
                     (1. - K.pow(self.beta_1, t)))

        ms = [K.zeros(K.int_shape(p), dtype=K.dtype(p)) for p in params]
        vs = [K.zeros(K.int_shape(p), dtype=K.dtype(p)) for p in params]

        self.weights = [self.iterations] + ms + vs

        for p, g, m, v in zip(params, grads, ms, vs):

            normalization, p_norm = get_normalization(p)
            g = normalization * g

            m_t = (self.beta_1 * m) + (1. - self.beta_1) * g
            v_t = (self.beta_2 * v) + (1. - self.beta_2) * K.square(g)
            p_t = p - lr_t * m_t / (K.sqrt(v_t) + self.epsilon)

            self.updates.append(K.update(m, m_t))
            self.updates.append(K.update(v, v_t))

            new_p = project(p_t, p_norm)

            # Apply constraints.
            if getattr(p, 'constraint', None) is not None:
                new_p = p.constraint(new_p)

            self.updates.append(K.update(p, new_p))
        return self.updates
```

That also still didn't do what I wanted, so lastly I tried to add a lambda layer that on the forward pass projects the points (although I have no idea if this proper). The target outputs are already coordinates in Hyperbolic space (so on the backward pass this should be a no-op).

```
def poincare_project(x, axis=-1):
    square_sum = K.tf.reduce_sum(
        K.tf.square(x), axis, keepdims=True)
    x_inv_norm = K.tf.rsqrt(square_sum)
    x_inv_norm = K.tf.minimum((1. - K.epsilon()) * x_inv_norm, 1.)
    outputs = K.tf.multiply(x, x_inv_norm)
    return outputs


x_dense = Dense(int(params["semantic_dense"]))(x_activation)
x_activation = activation(x_dense)
x_output = Dense(params["semantic_dim"], activation="tanh")(x_activation)
x_project = Lambda(poincare_project)(x_output)
```

But it still produces garbage results (doesn't minimize the distance, or causes NaN/Inf on subsequent evaluation). Now there might be a bug in any of these implementations, or the whole idea is just invalid. I can't really tell right now. The concrete goal is a form of supervised entity linking, where the input is a target word in a context (using pretrained fasttext vectors or even BERT embeddings), and the output is a point in the Poincare embedding representing a structured ontology (which was pretrained using the gensim implementation).

I did find a [paper](https://www.groundai.com/project/embedding-text-in-hyperbolic-spaces/1)([pdf](https://aclweb.org/anthology/W18-1708)) that tried to do this, by reparameterizing the model, but I wasn't able to gauge from their description how to implement this. It does describe the problem neatly though.

[image: the problem]

Comment: Hi! Any succes with this? Also need to implement this layer :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an implementation of Poincaré model in TensorFlow in the [HyperLib package](https://github.com/nalexai/hyperlib).

That package defines hyperbolic distance between points:

````py
def dist(self, x, y):
    """ Hyperbolic distance between points 
    Args:
        x, y: Tensors of size B x dim of points in the Poincare ball
    """
    norm = tf.norm(self.mobius_add(-x,y) + self.eps[x.dtype], 
                    axis=1, 
                    keepdims=True
                    )
    return 2./self._sqrt_c * atanh_( self._sqrt_c * norm)

def mobius_add(self, x, y):
    """Element-wise Mobius addition.
  Args:
    x: Tensor of size B x dimension representing hyperbolic points.
    y: Tensor of size B x dimension representing hyperbolic points.
    c: Tensor of size 1 representing the absolute hyperbolic curvature.
  Returns:
    Tensor of shape B x dimension representing the element-wise Mobius addition
    of x and y.
  """
    cx2 = self._c * tf.reduce_sum(x * x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    cy2 = self._c * tf.reduce_sum(y * y, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    cxy = self._c * tf.reduce_sum(x * y, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    num = (1 + 2 * cxy + cy2) * x + (1 - cx2) * y
    denom = 1 + 2 * cxy + cx2 * cy2
    return self.proj(num / tf.maximum(denom, self.min_norm)) 
```
````